# Extracting GPS info from EXIFcrashes Excel when retrieving GPSLongitudeDecimal

Tags: excel, vba, gps

I found a way to retrieve GPS information from the EXIF at  https://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Extracting-GPS-data-from-JPEG-files.

You can download the original Access files from https://www.everythingaccess.com/downloads/GPSExifReader.zip

I imported these VBA for Access Class Modules into Excel. I can retrieve all the GPS information **EXCEPT** the Decimal GPS Longitude.

As I understand this, the coder (Wayne Phillips) is executing code in the machine's memory to create a virtual COM object from the images, thus exposing the EXIF properties.

Everything runs, except the `Call VCOMObject.AssignVar(GPSLongitudeDecimal, VCOMObject.GPSLongitudeDecimal)` which is in the `Property Get GPSLongitudeDecimal() As Variant` procedure.

It crashes my Excel 2013 then restarts it. Tried commenting out the offending Call and works on every Property Get procedure. It's just the Longitude one that crashes without any apparent error being raised.

Thought it might be something weird on that longitude exif parameter so I tried with different jpegs, and with different jpegs from different cameras and the same thing happens.

Since this is an intricate piece of Class Modules voodoo, I'm providing a link to my Excel file (https://yiqyyh.s.cld.pt) just click "Download" on the left hand side of the webpage. The Rar file also has three test images with GPS information on their EXIF.

The easier way to test is by running the `UserForm1` UserForm and clicking `CommanButton1`. This will open a browse window to choose an image. If the textbox gets populated, then nothing bad happened, but if it crashes that's my problem.

*EDIT: I tried another machine and Excel 2013 crashed.*

*EDIT2: The other machine is in my work network. I tried running this on my home PC, also running Excel 2013, and **IT WORKED**. I need to run this at work.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as yours:
On 32bit versions of Office, the GPSExifReader worked fine. On 64bit versions, it froze when retrieving the `LongitudeDecimal` property (latitude and everything else worked fine).

I solved my problem by using another of Wayne Phillips' [excellent tools & tutorials](https://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Accessing-detailed-file-information-provided-by-the-Operating-System). The VBA modules downloadable from that link drag effortlessly into Excel and the tutorial makes it easy to write a macro that returns latitude *and* longitude.